# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: verifyItemInStock is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create an auxiliar method to use inside the same controller:

```
module.exports = {

  async update(req, res) {

    // code here...

    // method call
    this.verifyItemInStock()

    // more code here ...

  },

  // method declaration
  verifyItemInStock (itemId) {
      // more code...
  }

}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> (node:31904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError:
>   verifyItemInStock is not defined
>       at update (/home/netogerbi/workspaces/zombieresistance/zombieresistance/app/controllers/trade.controller.js:34:5)
>   (node:31904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:31904) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: This works for me. Can you add the code which explains how u r using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by the following:

```
const update = async (req, res) => {

  // auxiliar method declaration
  verifyItemInStock = itemId => {
      // code...
  }

  // ...
  // method call
  const hasItems = verifyItemInStock(id)

}
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `this` and make it more readable:

```
// method declaration
const verifyItemInStock = itemId => {
  // more code...
}

const update = async (req, res) => {
  // code here...
  // method call
  verifyItemInStock()
  // more code here ...
}


module.exports = {
  update,
  verifyItemInStock,
}
```

Also, the consumer of the promise should have a catch:

```
import { update } from './my-module';

update(req, res).then(...).catch(...)
// or
try {
  const resolved = await update(req, res);
  // consume the resolved value
} catch (e) {
  // exception handling
}
```